# Окно ошибки при загрузки картинки из БД

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe

При загрузке битой картинки из БД на форму, вылетает окно ошибки.
 Ошибка вылетает только в том случае, если в Image2 ничего нет, если там до этого была картинка ошибки нет.
Как выловить ошибку или хотя-бы выловить появление окна и не выводить его на экран?

```
TMemoryStream* strm = new TMemoryStream;
TJPEGImage *ptJpg = new TJPEGImage;

((TGraphicField*)Form1->IBDataSet2->FieldByName("Image"))->SaveToStream(strm);   
strm->Seek(0,0);

if (*(Word*)strm->Memory == 0xD8FF) Form1->Image2->Picture->Graphic=ptJpg;
{
    try
    {
        Form1->Image2->Picture->Graphic->LoadFromStream(strm);
    }
    catch(...)
    {

    }

    delete strm;
    delete ptJpg;
}
else 
{
    Form1->Image2->Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: В какой точно момент валит ошибка (лучше укажите сточку)?

Comment: ошибка в строке  Form1->Image2->Picture->Graphic->LoadFromStream(strm);  Сама ошибка "JPEG error #53"

Comment: К стати, сдается мне `delete strm;` надо делать за пределами `if`, а то утечка будет. А вообще, почему вы не создаете `strm` на стеке?

Comment: Вот неплохо разобрано как проверить что файл действительно jpeg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772388/c-sharp-how-can-i-test-a-file-is-a-jpeg?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Полезная ссылка.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772388/c-sharp-how-can-i-test-a-file-is-a-jpeg?lq=1) 

и после правки [Sergey Rufanov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17298/sergey-rufanov),  кода стал рабочим. Было изначально не правильно написано условие.